# Remove product price

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I am using magento 1.9 community edition.
How to remove or hide product price and "add to cart " button in specific magento store.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom module for this or change theme file directly.You can set display condition checking with current store with products for show and hide price and add to cart options.

Answer (score 1):

Create a yes/no product attribute and based on the value of this particular attribute call the price and add to cart block for the products on category(product list) page, product details page and other pages where you products can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

**How to hide product prices on the frontend in Magento**

If for some reason you want to remove product prices from being shown on the frontend of your Magento store, you can do that with a minor CSS modification.

You need to modify the styles.css file of your theme. For example, if you use the default theme that comes prepackaged with Magento and your store is installed directly in the public_html folder on your Magento hosting account,

making the frontend accessible at yourdomain.com, then the path to the file will be public_html/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css. Edit the file by adding the following on a new line:
.price-box {display:none;}

This will hide the price on category pages (both grid and list view) and on product details pages. You can edit the file from the Files section of the Pixie control panel. Another way to do it is to download it on your local computer with an FTP client (e.g. FileZilla), edit it with a text editor (e.g. Notepad) and upload it back overwriting the old file.

After that clear your browser cache and refresh the frontend of your site to see the result.

On a similar subject you may also find useful the article on removing the "Add to Cart" button from the frontend in Magento.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i need to hide it for some products ,not all of them, actually for one magento store, other stores products should display price and add to cart button

Comment: You might use a copy of that css then and use this css for one store and the one with the button and the price in the other store